# Why is everything in one heap in the Android Studio emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am learning Android Studio.

Making a calculator.

Why is everything (Summ button and fields for num 1, 2 and result) in one heap in the Android Studio emulator?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml layout information would probably help with diagnosing problems, Unconstrained views will all appear in top left corner.
if using constraintLayout, drag views to desired position in design View and set constraints, or use the magic wand.
Hope that helps ):

Answer (score 0):

One need to add ConstraintLayout to the white field in design mode (where your text and button are).

Then choose the element, rightclick it -> Constraint: parent top, bottom, start, end.
Then change numbers and drag the sliders (marked with blue).

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgE3C.png)